# Concatenating two characters to create escape sequence

Tags: c, string, special-characters, string-formatting

Idea is to try to create escape sequences 'human' way. For example, I use two characters to create `'\n'`, the `'\'` and `'n'`.
What I'm thinking about is `char array[3]={'\\','n','\0'};`
so I can change `'n'` character and still use it as an escape sequence.

When I `printf(array)` it now prints:

`\n`

and I'd like it to go to next line.

For example:
what if I wanted to check manually what every letter in alphabet does when used as escape sequence with a loop?

```
for(char='a';char<='z';char++) 
{
  /* create escape sequence with that letter */
  /* print that escape sequence and see what it does */
}
```

It's not an assignment,has no practical use (at least not yet), but just a theoretical question that I couldn't find answer anywhere, nor figure it out myself.

Comment: You are confusing runtime with compilation time. You will have to unescape the string yourself, i. e. check for an escape character being `n`, and then replace it with a newline.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is this, "Yes, it can be done", or "No, there's no way to do it" on my terms?

Comment: It can be done, but not in a way you wanted to do it.

Comment: It can't be done if the purpose is to discover undocumented escape sequences since the suggested "solution" is to interpret and escape the sequences yourself - you could *invent* any sequence that way.

Answer (score 2):

The escape sequence represents a *single character*  and is evaluated at *compile time*.  You cannot have a literal string interpreted as an escape sequence at *run time*. 
For example '\n' is a newline (or line-feed character - 0x0A in ASCII)

Note that:

```
char array[3]={'\\','n','\0'};
```

is equivalent to:

```
 char array[3] = "\\n" ;
```

so perhaps unsurprisingly when you `printf(array)` it prints `\n` - that is what you have asked it to do.

Undefined escape sequences simply won't compile, so you might simply:

```
char = '\a' ;
char = '\b' ;
... // etc.
```

and see which lines the compiler baulks at.  However that is not the complete story because some escape sequences require *operands*, for example `\x` on its own has no meaning, whereas `\xab` is the character represented by 0xab (171 decimal). Others are not even letters. Most are related to white-space, and their effect may be dependent on the terminal or console capabilities of the execution platform. So a naive investigation may not generate the results you seek, because it does not account for the language semantics or platform capabilities.

All supported escape sequences are in fact well defined - you'll find few surprises except perhaps those related to platform capabilities (for example if your target has no means to generate a beep, \a will have no useful effect):

```
    \a      Beep
    \b      Backspace
    \f      Form-feed
    \n      Newline
    \r      Carriage return
    \t      Horizontal tab
    \v      Vertical tab
    \\      Backslash
    \'      Single quotation mark
    \"      Double quotation mark
    \0      ASCII 0x00 (null terminator)
    \ooo    Octal representation
    \xdd    Hexadecimal representation
```

Answer (score 0):

What about writing your own printf()?
Where you can check for a '\' followed by a 'n' and than only print from char[0] to '\''n'. Finally add "printf("\n");

mfg

Comment: I'd still have to replace every \n with corresponding escape sequence manually.

Comment: Runtime translation of escape sequences will not address his aim to investigate the effect of arbitrary escape sequences. An aim that is not realisable in fact because it is based on a misconception about how and when escape sequences are evaluated.